# How can I modify my class to override a list add?

Tags: c#

I am using the following class that was suggested to me to track timings:

```
public sealed class TimeEvent
{
  public long Elapsed {get; private set;}
  public string Description { get; private set;}
  public TimeEvent(long elapsedTime, string descriptionOfEvent)
  {
    this.Elapsed = elapsedTime;
    this.Description = descriptionOfEvent;
  }
}
```

Here's my class that holds the list of times:

```
public abstract class BaseGridViewModel
{

    protected BaseGridViewModel()
    {
        Times = new List<TimeEvent>();
    }
    public IList<TimeEvent> Times {get; set;}

}
```

Here's how a start the stopwatch and add an event:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
vm.Times.Add(new TimeEvent(sw.ElapsedMillisends, "After event 1"));
sw.Stop();
```

Is there a way that I could make it so that I have a method inside my viewmodel that I could pass the values to and it would then do the same as the Add internally. For example a method like this:

```
vm.Event(sw, "After event 1"));
```

Even

Comment: I'm not quite sure what u mean "adding method inside"; however, you just wrapped the "Add()" or write a lambda expression inside to an Add<>().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not?

```
public abstract class BaseGridViewModel
{

    protected BaseGridViewModel()
    {
        Times = new List<TimeEvent>();
    }
    public IList<TimeEvent> Times {get; set;}

    public void Event(StopWatch watch, string message)
    {
        Times.Add(new TimeEvent(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, message));
    }

}
```